# Change number of mandatory arguments depends on option (argparse)

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to make with argparse simple command line:

```
usage: downtime [-h] [-d] [-l | -f] [-s] host duration

positional arguments:
  host            Host to schedule. Local fqdn used if not specified.
  duration        Duration of downtime (minutes), 15 if not specified

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  -d, --debug     Print debug info
  -l, --flexible  Use f_L_exible downtime (used by default)
  -f, --fixed     Use _F_ixed downtime
```

And I want to add '-s' - 'show' option:

```
foobar -s host
   -s           Show info for host
```

I can't find way to say argparse 'change meaning of positional arguments if there is "-s" switch. Or at least make 'number' optional.

How can I do this, or this is impossible with argparse? Thanks.

Code:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('host', help = "Host to schedule. Local fqdn used if not specified.", nargs = '?'  default=alias)
p.add_argument('duration', type = int, help = 'Duration of downtime (minutes), 15 if not specified', default=15)
p.add_argument('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', help = 'Print debug info')
g = p.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g.add_argument('-l', '--flexible', help = "Use f_L_exible downtime (used by default)", action='store_true')
g.add_argument('-f', '--fixed', help = 'Use _F_ixed downtime', action="store_false")
mode2 = p.add_argument_group('show')
mode2.add_argument('-s', '--show', help = 'show downtimes for host', action="store_true")
args = p.parse_args()
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - what do you currently have, what are you expecting, and what happens instead?

Comment: You could try using [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/), but i do feel it should be possible to do what you want in argparse. Include some code, and an actual description of what you want to do. How is the program meant to work?

Comment: Is that first block the actual `help`, or just a desired one?  Show us the `argparse` code, at least as far as you've got it.  It's easier to suggest changes that way.  The `[host]` implies that you already know about `nargs='?'`.

Comment: Yes. The real code added to the question. -s is more than 'help', it should do some work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `nargs='?'` to duration:

```
p.add_argument('duration', type = int, nargs='?', help = 'Duration of downtime (minutes), 15 if not specified', default=15)
```

changes the usage to:

```
usage: downtime [-h] [-d] [-l | -f] [-s] host [duration]
```

With this change, `duration` is always optional.  Before it was required, and 'default=15' did nothing.  Now the default means something.

It looks like `host` is required always. That's a good thing, since have more than one 'optional' positional complicates matters (it's possible, but trickier).

`-s` is used with something like:

```
if args.s:
    print_show(args.host)
    # ignore args.duration regardless of whether it is default or not
    # or object if args.duration  is not its default value
else:
    <do something else with args.host and args.duration>
```

Comment: Yes, I've made 'duration' nargs='?' and it now works as expecting. Thanks!